# WordPress - Connection FTP failed in XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, macos, ftp, xampp

I'm trying to install plugins in localhost, but I can’t install themes and plugins. The main problem is the username and password is invalid, but I'm 100% sure that is my username/password. I tried to log out, reset, clear the cache and google, but it doesn’t help me...

This is the error I get:

> Connection Information
>
> To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web
> server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not
> remember your credentials, you should contact your web host

How do I fix it?

I'm using XAMPP and [OS X v10.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan).

Answer (score 0):

This means that WordPress is having limited permissions for making changes in the folder that it was installed.

In order to fix this, all that you need to do is provide necessary permissions for the same.

Run the following command in your terminal, [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY), command line prompt after connecting to your server via SSH.

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
```

Checkout the below article for full details (Syam | MMWYS.Online):

*[How to fix the infamous issue of WordPress asking for FTP Credentials for Installing Plugins / Themes?](http://mmwys.online/2016/08/04/how-to-fix-the-infamous-issue-of-wordpress-asking-for-ftp-credentials-for-installing-plugins-themes/#more-142)*

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. If JavaScript is enabled, there is a number of apparently dubious redirects (to ad sites).